# What does new [size_t] + 1 return

Tags: c++, pointers, return, new-operator

The following sample of code if from a book "C++ von A bis Z" (second edition, translation: C++ from A to Z) at page 364. The sample is wrong.

```
// overload operator +=
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class String {
private:
    char* buffer;
    unsigned int len;

public:
    String(const char* s="") {
        // cout << "Constructor: " << s << "\n";
        len = strlen(s);
        buffer = new char [len+1];
        strcpy(buffer, s);
    }
    ~String() {
        // cout << "Destructor: " << buffer << "\n";
        delete [] buffer;
    }
    String(const String& s) {
        // cout << "Copy_Constructor: " << s.get_buffer() << "\n";
        len = s.len;
        buffer = new char [len+1];
        strcpy(buffer, s.buffer);
    }
    char* get_buffer() const {
        return buffer;
    }

    // returning a reference is more efficent
    // String& operater+=(const String& str1)
    String operator+=(const String& str1) {
        // cout << "Assignment_Operator +=: " << str1.get_buffer() << "\n";
        String tmp(*this);
        delete [] buffer;
        len = tmp.len + str1.len;
        // invalid pointer
        // buffer = new char[len+1];
        buffer = new char [len]+1;
        strcpy(buffer, tmp.buffer);
        strcat(buffer, str1.buffer);
        // wrong return_type
        // return *this;
        return buffer;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    String string1("Adam");
    String string2("Eva");
    string1+=" und ";
    string1.operator+=(string2);
    cout << string1.get_buffer() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The lines with the comments are my "fixes". Now I want to know what "new char [len]+1" does? I think the following:

- it allocates sizeof(char)*len memory from heap
- and returns the WRONG address to the pointer *buffer
- but what is the wrong address: "first address of the new memory on heap + 1" or "first address of the new memory on heap + sizeof(char)*1)?

What happens?
Thanks

// edit
Thank you all! You helped me!
I just wanted to know, what this statement will return.

```
new char [len]+1;
```

The line itself is, of course, a typo from the author of the book.

Comment: How is your third point different? `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition.

Comment: Also, who gives a crap -- if you're doing C++, forget about `char*` and `strcpy` and raw arrays.

Comment: I guess you're right in all your assumptions. The returned address is "first address of the new memory on heap + sizeof(char)*1", but that makes no sense for this code anyway.

Comment: It's a rite of passage or something, writing your own string class.  Can't say i get it, considering `std::string`, but eh.

Comment: @KerrekSB: it's all very well telling newbies to forget about `char*`, but are you certain you want them to not understand why `"hello, " + "world"` doesn't work? They'll end up asking on SO eventually, and they'll be chided for not knowing about `char*`. Implementing a string class is perhaps more than they strictly need, but I'd prefer them to know roughly how one works.

Comment: @cHao: it's because one of the interesting things about the design of C++ is that you're *supposed* to be able to implement this and similar classes in "user mode" (by which I mean not requiring special compiler/runtime support or optimized code written in other languages) with no greater overhead than the standard implementation. Granted, not many people actually use that aspect of C++ in their everyday lives, but if you're going to learn C++ you might as well learn its alleged major features. The issue is that if you do this first, you might come away thinking all C++ code is low-level.

Comment: @Kerrek SB or generally everybody who writes "you don't need feature $foobar of language": Don't take this as personal critic! It is a sample for learning C++ and for using C++ everyone must know how cstrings and pointers work. Also the user should know, a little bit about, how the Template-Class "string" from C++ works. C++ is a superset of C, so a good programmer  of C++ must able to read and use C. And finally, learning must start with low-level stuff and not high-level. Thats why every good book starts with "Hello world!" and not with "Quicksort" :-) Thanks

Comment: @Peter: "learning must start with low-level stuff and not high-level" I don't think that's true at all. The reason books start with "hello world" and not "quicksort" is that they have to start *simple*, not that they have to start *low-level*. And anyway, the archetypical C++ "hello, world" is the high-level `std::cout << "hello, world\n";`, not the lower-level `std::puts("hello, world");`. Often high-level is simpler and also easier to understand, and you work towards low-level. Consider chemistry, for example, you don't learn Schrödinger equations for electrons before you learn valency.

Comment: Hehe! We don't need to know everything, we can't know everything! Knowing foundations of Assembler for writing C/C++ is not important. Knowing the foundations from char,cstring and string in C/C++ are important. Or in other words, knowing what an atom is important today, knowing what a quark is (currently) not important. I saw very often comments like "don't learn this", "don't try to understand", "use the high-level stuff, it is less difficult". That is the wrong way. See - "When the Bough Breaks" (Star Trek: The Next Generation)

Answer (score 4):

Let's break it down:

```
new char[len];
```

returns a pointer to an array of `char`.

```
new char[len] + 1;
```

returns the next address in memory.

It's basically cutting off the first character.

EDIT: As others have mentioned, this is most probably a typo, it should be `new char[len+1]`. I'm just explaining what the code does, but you should only use pointer arithmetics if you really know what you're doing. Trying to delete the returned pointer would be UB, as cHao pointed out. You'll also get UB if `len == 1` and attempt to work with the returned pointer.

Comment: And, of course, setting `buffer` to a pointer that invoke UB when you go to delete it.

Comment: It should be clarified that "the next address in memory" means "the current address + sizeof(char)" and not "the current address + 1" (even though that amounts to the same thing in the case of char) as that was the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

If you add an integer `i` to a `T*`, this will add `sizeof(T) * i` to the pointer. So in this case, since `new char[len]` returns a `char*`, `+ 1` will indeed add `sizeof(char) * 1` to it.

Answer (score 0):

`new Type[size] + 1` will allocate an array of size `size` and yield the address of the element with index 1 - that the second element. Nothing special, just pointer arithmetic. `new[]` would yield the address of the element with index 0 and size `+1` is done on that address it yields address of element with index `1`.

Answer (score 0):

It simply returns the pointer to the **second** array item =)
Read about C pointers ;)

Answer (score 0):

`+sizeof(char)*1`, but I failed to see why did you do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a typo, and it should be `new char [len+1]`. The `+1` is for the string terminator character that must exist.

Comment: The way I read it the OP is fully aware that the line is wrong and how to fix it (if you look at the comments he already did fix it). He's just asking what exactly the wrong line would do.